# Powershell Change data in a CSV's column, that has no headers

Tags: powershell

I need to change a CSV column, that has no headers.

Here's my test data WITH HEADERS:
data.csv:

```
order|color|shape
1|green|square
1|red|rectangle
```

And here's what i used to change the first column to 0.

```
$ImportedCSV = Import-CSV data.csv -Delimiter '|'
$NewCSV = Foreach ($Entry in $ImportedCsv) {
    Switch ($Entry."order") {
        1 {$Entry."order" = "0"}
    }
    $Entry
}
$NewCSV | Export-CSV done.csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation

(Get-Content -Path done.csv ).Replace('"','') | Set-Content -Path done.csv
```

The result is this:

```
order|color|shape
0|green|square
0|red|rectangle
```

My data.csv wont have headers to start with.
Can "Switch ($Entry."order")" use column numbers rather than the header name?
So, something like "Column 1" rather then "order"?

Please no mention of simply adding the headers then delete the headers when done.
In the end, i need to change a column's data based on column number, rather than header name.
So...replace ($Entry."order") with what?
($Entry.Column 1) = nope
($Entry.Column-1) = nope
Thanks for any help.

Comment: the `Import-CSV` cmdlet has a `-Header` parameter that will allow you to set your header line when the file itself has none. take a look at `Get-Help Import-CSV` for more info. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have:

data_noheader.csv

```
7|green|square
8|red|rectangle
9|blue|triangle
```

And you want to change the green square (in the first row) to purple and the item where `col0` is `8` to gold star.

A few things change:

1. Explicitly set the header with `-Header` so that the first line isn't treated as the header.
2. Edit `$NewCSV` in place rather than composing it with `ForEach` (this isn't required but makes the code a bit easier to follow and work with)
3. Instead of looping `ForEach` and looking at the column name the row is selected explicitly for things that you want to change by the actual row.
4. For things that you want to change based on the value of a column use a similar pattern to the one you used before and just check the value.
5. Strip the header back off with `Select-Object -Skip 1`

```
$NewCSV = Import-CSV data_noheader.csv -Delimiter '|' -Header @("col0", "col1", "col2")
$NewCSV[0].col1 = "purple" # Set based on the actual row position
ForEach ($Entry in $NewCSV) {
    If ($Entry.col0 -Eq "8") { # Modify data in other columns in a row based on the value of a particular column
        $Entry.col1 = "gold"
        $Entry.col2 = "star"
    }
}
$NewCSV | Export-CSV done_noheader.csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation

(Get-Content -Path done_noheader.csv ).Replace('"','') | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path done_noheader.csv
```

The result in done_noheader.csv will now be:

```
7|purple|square
8|gold|star
9|blue|triangle
```

Comment: Thx, this explains more than i really need. What i need is to change the first column to all zeros. Your second line does the first row. This, $NewCSV[0].col1 = "0" will do the first row. What do i put here, [?], for all rows? Sry, I'm a novice.

Comment: To do it for all rows you'll want to use a for or foreach loop

Comment: Yep, thx... Just worked that out. Thanks for the help. Two thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

In case the delimiter is known and unique (not part of quoted column data)

You can obtain column count

```
$delim = '|'
$Cols = (get-Content .\data.csv|select -first 1).split($delim).Count
```

And automatically apply numbered Header

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\data.csv -Delim $delim -Header @(1..$Cols)
```

---

```
> $csv

1 2      3
- -      -
7 purple square
8 gold   star
9 blue   triangle
```

Manipulate the columns in a ForEach

```
$csv | ForEach-Object { $_.1 = 0 }
```

---

```
> $csv

1 2      3
- -      -
0 purple square
0 gold   star
0 blue   triangle
```

And lateron save, stripping quotes and header if neccessary.